# Yellow line in console when writing large amounts of text

Tags: c#, console

My program is writing a string with multiple lines of just █ to console. This is done with a
Stringbuiler and its ToString().

However there is a yellow line bleeding through the same place every time and only when drawing a lot of █:
[Image with yellow line bleeding, CursorVisible set on true temporary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgjAT.png)

It's hard to see in the image and hard to explain, but different parts of the lines are phasing in and out while the program is running. It makes me believe it's not the code but the console itself.

Colours are not being used or changed except for the background colour. But that will be set to Black again.

Changing the window size while it was writing to console helped to move it to a place where nothing was being written, thus making it dissapear but leaving a big empty void.
It reappears in the same spot if you maximise the console window or when changing the size back.

Comment: Looks looks a problem with your graphics card or monitor.

Comment: @KlausGütter Nope, just ran it on my laptop with different specs and it shows there as well

Comment: If you would share your code, others could try it out on their computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to the WindowSize and BufferSize. I had to fill in the empty space with the ASCII for SPACE and then the artifacting went away.

It's weirdly inconsistent in when this yellow line artifacting appears. As I was not able to always reproduce it. I'm unsure if this is a permanent solution to this problem, but so far testing hasn't been able to get this yellow line again. That's why I'll be marking this as solved.